# Access and modify value of a key that contains dots on name in a JSON file from terminal / Change zoom level of Visual Studio Code from terminal

Tags: text-processing, json, jq

Thank you for any help that you could provide.

I am trying to create a bash script to modify the value of a key from the settings.json file from Visual Studio Code.

The key that I want to modify is `window.zoomLevel`. I have tried to read it by using jq: `jq -r '.window.zoomLevel' settings.json`, `jq -r 'window.zoomLevel' settings.json`, or `jq -r '.zoomLevel' settings.json`, but I am not able to and I even get compile errors. I created a copy of settings.json and changed the name of the variable to `window_zoomLevel` and I was able to successfully read it with the same code: `jq -r '.window_zoomLevel' settings.json`. How can I access that variable without modifying the json file?

As you can imagine, I don't know much about json structures, so please help me out.

This is how the file looks:

```
{
    "security.workspace.trust.untrustedFiles": "open",
    "launch": {
        "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "bashdb",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Bash-Debug (hardcoded script name)",
            "cwd": "${/.../...}",
            "program": "$/.../....sh",
            "args": []
        }
        ]
    },
    "kite.showWelcomeNotificationOnStartup": false,
    "editor.fontSize": 10,
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "screencastMode.fontSize": 20,
    "scm.inputFontSize": 10,
    "debug.console.fontSize": 10,
    "terminal.integrated.fontSize": 10,
    "markdown.preview.fontSize": 10,
    "window.zoomLevel": -1.5,
    "editor.mouseWheelZoom": true
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I finally was able to read the variable and modified it with this code that I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43292243/how-to-modify-a-keys-value-in-a-json-file-from-command-line):

```
mv settings.json temp.json &&
jq -r '."window.zoomLevel" |= -1.5' temp.json > settings.json &&
rm temp.json
```

It was basically a problem with quotes and so on [`."window.zoomLevel"` vs **`'."window.zoomLevel"'`** (correct one)]. If anyone can explain this in further detail, I would appreciate it, but at least I was able to do what I wanted.

Comment: It's mentioned in the [Basic Filters](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#TypesandValues) section of the documentation: *"If the key contains special characters or starts with a digit, you need to surround it with double quotes like this: `."foo$"`, or else `.["foo$"]`"* The period `.` is a special character.

Comment: Oh, thank you! I wasn't sure how to look for it and was feeling lost in the jq documentation, but it makes sense now.

Comment: Put a `&&` after each of the first 2 lines so you only execute the next line if the current one succeeds or you'll end up trashing your input file on any failure. The more common idiom, though, is `cmd input > tmp && mv tmp input` rather than `mv input tmp && cmd tmp > input && rm tmp`.

Comment: Oh, thank you for that! I thought that if jq didn't parse correctly, then it would not modify the text, but I will add it to make sure that the file is not corrupted! Thank you!